# sending value to another method in another class in JAVA

Tags: java, methods

sorry I'm new to java. I want to pass the mark1 to class Exam in method Calculator, but I got some error how can i do that the program say incompatibe type. What can I do?

I want to send mark1 from this method:

```
public float SendMark(){
    Exam ex = new Exam();
    for (int i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
        mark1 = students[i].getMark();
    }
    return ex.Calculator(mark1);
}
```

to this class and method calculator ... but it say incompatible type ... to this method i want to sum the Array value and get average of the array values ... is it correct way ?? what should i write here ...?  please help me details thanks ...

```
public class Exam {
    public Calculator (float mark1) {
        AddList ad = new AddList();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the complete code. What is the type of mark1?

Comment: You should consider checking the [Sun's coding convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html) to improve your code clarity. You really need it.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing the return type for the method calculator.

```
public Calculator (float mark1)
```

should be

```
public float Calculator (float mark1)
```

Comment: But i dont want to return in method calculator ... i want the calculator method get the mark1 and calculate it and then print it for me ... is it correct concept ??

Answer (score 0):

Your `Calculator` method does not have a return statement and its signature (the method header) does not declare a return type.
Also, I can't see where you declared `mark1`, you only initialized it in the `for` loop.
Meanwhile, I also spotted a logic error, the `mark1` will always send the last score in the array because its value would be repeatedly overwritten in the loop; only the last value survives.

Comment: So what can i do here ...?? may you tell me the exact what should i do to send all the array value to the method calculator ??

Comment: Can you fully explain what you are trying to achieve? From the post, I can't figure out why you needed the _for_ loop. I can only tell you what to do when I know exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: well i want to send the mark1 that i declare it in the class AddList totally i want to sent the getmark method thats the grade of students to the class Exam In method calculator and in this method i want to sum all the array values and divide it to the number of array values But my problem is how send the all Array valuse to the method calculator values are the mark of students and are type float ...  sorry for my bad english  ....

Comment: Well then, you do not need `calculator`. Just create a variable `total` and in your loop, add each value to `total`. After the loop, divide `total` by `array.length`. That should give you the average. Adding the calculator introduces unnecessary complexities.

Comment: if i want to calculate the average in calculate method in Exam class, how can i send the mark array values to method calculate and there doing the calculate of total ???

Comment: Create a `calculateAverage(float[] input)` method in class `Exam` then. So instead of looping through and sending the values one at a time, you simple hand the method a reference to the original array. So your `sendMark` would just have `return ex.calculateAverage(sudents);`
Please not that my method name is a verb (calculateAverage) as opposed to yours (Calculator), this is because methods are supposed to represent actions.

Comment: i did that, create calculateAverage(float[] input) method in class exam and in sendmark return ex.calculateAverage(students) but i got the error saying method calculateAverage can not be applied to given types ... what can i do ?

Comment: Your code didn't show the declaration of `students`. Make sure you declare `students` as a `float[]` too.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not need return type, you type `void method_name(args)`, like in C. `Void` is the placeholder for *no return type*. Secondly, your code is better than of other noobs, but you still have a lot of unnecessary details, which means that you did not debug yourself. Localize the problem better (remove everything unnecessary to reproduce). It will be simpler then for experts to see your problem immediately. You will even see or guess it yourself. Otherwise, without learning localizing the bugs, you will never become a programmer. And garbage the SO unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

there are several small problems in your codes:

- usually method name should start with lower letter in java code convention
- what does the `for` loop in `SendMark` method do? just overwrite a float variable many times?
- in your comment, you mentioned you want `Exam.Calculator` method print result, but no return value. Then you should add `void` as return type to method `Calculator()`.
- if you don't expect any return value from `Calculator()` method, why you `return ex.Calculator(mark1)` in your `SendMark()` method, and type is float?

Comment: i want to send array values that here is getmark to calculator method to average them .. how can i do that so ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood from your question, here is my answer.

```
   public float **s**endMark(){
        Exam ex = new Exam();
        for (int i=0; i<students.length; i++) {
            mark1 = students[i].getMark(); //this does not make any sense.
        }
        //Since you insisted that you wanted to only print, just call the calculator method and do not return anything. change the return type of calculator method to void.
        ex.Calculator(mark1);
        return "something";//since your method's definition says so
   }

public class Exam {
    public void **c**alculator (float mark1) {
        //Do your stuff

    }
}
```

You may also want to look into sun java's coding conventions.

Comment: in (mark1 = students[i].getmark) i want to collect all the array value to the mark1 variable  ... with this code (return ex.calculator(mark1)) i want to send the mark1 to calculator method, is this correct ??

Comment: what should i return in sendmark class? should i return mark1 to the calculator method ?? how can i do that ?

Comment: For your first comment, if you want to collect all the value then, you should initialize mark1 to an appropriate value outside your loop and then inside your loop you should have the following piece of code  mark1=mark1+students[i].getmark(); so that you can have all the values of the array in mark1 variable. If you just do mark1=students[i].getmark(),each time new value will be stored and at the end only the last value will be stored.

Comment: @user1935321: For your second comment, it depends on what you want to do with your sendMark() method. Currently, your method returntype is float i.e, public **float** sendMark(). Hence I said return whatever you would want to return to the calling method. If you do not want to return anything, then change the method definition to void. Since you said you are a newbie to java, you may want to first read and understand java basics which will help you get clarity on methods, return types and so on so that you can get your basic doubts clarified.

Answer (score 0):

one of the approach is to pass your students array to calculator and inside calclator method iterate over student sum up marks like
marks = marks + students[i].getMark() and avg = marks/students.length

other could be, form marks i your main method by marks = marks + students[i].getMark() and then pass marks and length to calculator method to calculate average.

Also please go through java coding conventions and how to pick return types.

hope this helps.